# Laravel Eloquent getting single dimensioned array from database

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Possibly there's an out-the-box method that will do all this for me!

I need to get an array (to put into a select box) in the form i.e. **the expected output**:

```
array: [
  "4" => "Siemens"
  "5" => "Dell"
]
```

Currently I'm doing (using Eloquent):

`$array = $this->get(['id','manufacturer'])->toArray();`

Which produces:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "manufacturer" => "Siemens"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "manufacturer" => "Dell"
  ]
]
```

I'm then doing:

```
$test = [];
$i=0;
$key='';
$value='';
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($it as $v) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        $key = $v;
        array_push($test,[$key=>$value]);
    } else {
        $value = $v;

    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    4 => "Siemens"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    5 => "Dell"
  ]
]
```

Which is very close...!  I'm a bit stuck on the final bit, but wondering if there's a better way to solve this altogether?

Comment: What is your expected output supposed to look like? Or maybe I misread, what does the array look like at start?

Comment: What result would you like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more digging and turns out that Eloquent's `pluck` method achieves exactly this

`$manufacturers->pluck('manufacturer','id');`

returns:

```
Collection {#562 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    4 => "Siemens"
    5 => "Dell"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can mark your answer which will help future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Array_combine and array_column can do what you need.

```
$arr =[
   0 => [
      "id" => 4,
      "manufacturer" => "Siemens",
   ],
   1 => [
      "id" => 5,
      "manufacturer" => "Dell"
   ]
];

$res = array_combine(array_column($arr, "id"), array_column($arr, "manufacturer"));
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/4f495